# What does the phrase "freakier side and geekier side" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "freakier side and less the geekier side" in the following text:

[*I wanted the show to play into this post-revolutionary time, to lean a little bit more into the Mad Max version of Star Wars,”he says from his L.A. office. “More of the freakier side and less the geekier side.*](https://apps.apple.com/us/story/id1484527615)

The text is from the description of the show *The Mandalorian*, which is the first-ever Star Wars live-action TV series.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

More of A and less of B: speaking of a mixture of two things, he says there will be more of A in the mixture and less of B.

A is "the freakier side"
B is "the geekier side".

The word "side" means approximately "aspect" or "character".

Both "freakier" and "geekier" are comparatives, but that's not important. It would mean the same if it said "more of the freaky side and less of the geeky side."

Now, "freaky" can mean strange or eccentric, even frightening.
"Geeky" means inclined toward fascination with technology.

So, paraphrasing, "more weirdness, less technology" in the makeup of the show.